# Simple RabbitMQ client wrapper

Tags: beginner, f#

After reading [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43893/first-real-world-f-application-how-good-idiomatic-is-it-long?stw=2), I've realized that I can do a lot to improve the quality of my question, so I've edited this question quite a bit.

I've been teaching myself F# in my spare time off and on for the last 6 months.  I've finally started getting comfortable enough with the language to feel that a lot of my code could be much better.  The problem is, I don't know what changes to make.

Here's what I'm interested in:

- I'm using higher order functions to return functions for interacting with a specific message queue.  Is this a good design.  Would another F# developer feel comfortable with this?
- Does this fit the idiomatic style of F#?
- If you know RabbitMQ, are there any bugs which I may be creating here.

Here's the context of the little block of code:

I'm doing a lot of experiments with messaging systems and I've been using RabbitMQ as a messaging framework.  There's a .Net library for RabbitMQ but it's written in and for C#.  I can use it in F# but it feels clunky.  I wanted a small wrapper around the RabbitMQ library which which convert it into a more functional interface.  Also, this will hopefully make it very easy to use RabbitMQ in an F# program.

My wrapper handles the following for RabbitMQ:

1. Connect to a RabbitMQ server
2. Create a function which will let you read one message from a queue
3. Create a function which will write a message to a queue
4. For both 2 and 3, if the queue doesn't exist, the queue will be created (that's the `declareQueue`)

   ```
   module Client =
       let connectToRabbitMqServerAt address = 
           let factory = new ConnectionFactory(HostName = address)
           factory.CreateConnection()

       let openChannelOn (connection:IConnection) = connection.CreateModel()

       let private declareQueue (channel:IModel) queueName = 
           channel.QueueDeclare( queueName, false, false, false, null )

       let private publishToQueue (channel:IModel) queueName (message:string) =
           let body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)
           channel.BasicPublish("", queueName, null, body)

       let createQueueReader channel queue = 
           declareQueue channel queue |> ignore

           fun () -> 
               let ea = channel.BasicGet(queue, true)
               if ea <> null then
                   let body = ea.Body
                   let message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body)
                   Some message
               else
                   None

       let createQueueWriter channel queue =
           declareQueue channel queue |> ignore
           publishToQueue channel queue
   ```

An example use case would be:

```
// open a connection to a RabbitMQ broker
let connection = connectToRabbitMqServerAt "localhost"
let myChannel = openChannelOn connection

// Connect to a queue for writing
let writeToHelloQueue = createQueueWriter myChannel "hello"

// write the message "Hello, World" to the queue "hello"
"Hello, World" |> writeToHelloQueue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, this code looks very good.  Just two nitpicks here:

1. Give your function definitions lines to themselves:

> ```
> let openChannelOn (connection:IConnection) = connection.CreateModel()
> ```

2. Use `match` statements unless you are checking a boolean value directly:

> ```
> if ea <> null then
>     let body = ea.Body
>     let message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body)
>     Some message
> else
>     None
> ```

Becomes:

```
match ea with
| null -> None
| _ ->
    let body = ea.Body
    let message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body)
    Some message
```